# pdfMake - how to get each table data group starts on a new page

Tags: angular, typescript, lodash, pdfmake

With the following code:    [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ppxt4o)

```
itemsArray = [
    { id : 'A1', name : 'Name A1'},
    { id : 'B2', name : 'nameB2'},
    { id : 'A3', name : 'nameA3'},
    { id : 'A2', name : 'nameA2'},
    { id : 'B1', name : 'nameB1'},
];

constructor() {
    pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
}

getItems(): void {
        this.items = _.orderBy(
            this.itemsArray,
            item => [ item.id, ],
            ['asc']
        );
        this.groupedItems =  _.groupBy( this.items,  item => [ item.id.substring(0,1)] );
}

buildTableBody(data, columns): any {
    const body = [];
    body.push(columns);

    data.forEach((row) => {
        const dataRow = [];
        columns.forEach((column) => {
            if (column.text === 'id')
            {
                dataRow.push(row['id']);
            }
            else if (column.text === 'name')
            {
                dataRow.push(row['name']);
            }
        });
        body.push(dataRow);
    });
    return body;
}

table(data, columns): any {

    return {
        table: {
            headerRows: 1,
            body: this.buildTableBody(data, columns),
        },
    };
}

createPdf(): void {
    this.getItems();
    console.log(this.groupedItems);

    const dd = {
        content: [
            this.table(
                this.items,
                [{ text: 'id'}, { text: 'name'}],
            ),
    ],
    };
    pdfMake.createPdf(dd).open();
}
```

I got the below result

[image]

But could not find a way to split the data groups, where each group should start on a new page:

group A:

[image]

group B:

[image]

Does someone can help on this ?